# Load CKEDITOR in angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, systemjs

Alright, for the life of me I can't figure out how to load CKEDITOR in angular 2.

I  have ran

```
"typings install dt~ckeditor --global --save"
```

ckeditor is located at /lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js so in my system.config.js in the map section I have:

```
"CKEDITOR": 'lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'
```

now I can't figure out how to import this into an angular 2 component.

I have added a refence tag (/// <reference...>) and the didn't work. I am totally stuck

**EDIT**

Here is my system.config.js

```
 /**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'moment':                     'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
    'ckeditor' :                   'node_modules/ckeditor'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ckeditor':                   { main:'ckeditor.js', defaultExtension:'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Comment: It sounds like I haven't dont much but I have been searching for hours and haven't found anything

Answer (score 1):

Installing Typings only adds type checking for you , and it does not import the library it self, i will show two ways to add ckeditor 
one way is to import it with a path in your component like this  :
( i installed ckeditor via npm with the command npm install ckeditor -S so replace my path with yours)

```
import { Component, ElementRef , AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
let ckeditor = require("node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js");
@Component( {
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.tmpl.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit
{
    ngAfterViewInit()
    {

        ckeditor.basePath="/node_modules/ckeditor/";
        console.log(ckeditor);
        ckeditor.replace('sample');

    }
}
```

you can add the ckeditor type via : to the variable i defined , and benefit from type checking , also don't forget to add the basePath as it's necceasary for ckeditor to find its dependencies.
another way is to load it via systemJs , for this solution go to your system.config.js file and add these lines to it :

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'src', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
    ,'ckeditor' :                   'node_modules/ckeditor/'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    ,'ckeditor':                  {main:'ckeditor.js',defaultExtension:'js'}
  };
```

now mind the ckeditor parts i defined in both the map and the packages object as they are both neccessary
now in your component you can import it like this:

```
import { Component, ElementRef , AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
//let ckeditor = require("node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js");
import * as ckeditor from "ckeditor";
@Component( {
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.tmpl.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit
{
    ngAfterViewInit()
    {

        ckeditor.basePath="/node_modules/ckeditor/";
        console.log(ckeditor);
        ckeditor.replace('sample');

    }
}
```

Comment: I got the let ckeditor = ... working but the import keeps saying it cant find the module 'ckeditor'

Comment: have you configured typescript in tsconfig.json correclty ? like setting its module system to commonjs and module resolution to node ?

Comment: also tell me what is the error you get ,maybe it's because of a path related problem

Comment: I editted my answer and include my system.config.js and I just get can't find module ckeditor. When I  use let ckeditor = ...  I don't get an editor but when I console.log(ckeditor) it just has one property and it is the base path I set in ngOnInit

Comment: okay thanks for the update , i told you to replace my path with yours so in the map object replace the ckeditor part with  'ckeditor' :'lib/ckeditor/' and don't change the path object that one is okay.basically your problem is it cannot find the path ckeditor is located play with it some time you will figure it out

Comment: I removed ckeditor from /lib and installed it npm. It is in the node modules folder but its still not working

Comment: i've no idea then, you don't get any errors like 404 or something similar ?

Comment: i just saw you said ngOnInit try ngAfterViewInit if you put it on ngOninit